# Is it right to use Expectation value for calculating conditional Expectation value?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

Consider a Poisson process with rate $\lambda$. Since the Inter-arrival time follows exponential distribution, the expectation value of the inter-arrival time in general is $E[X]= \frac 1 \lambda$.

If I consider a particular time interval $[0,1 \text{ s}]$, Then, ***what would be the expectation value of the arrival time $X_1,X_2,X_3,\ldots$ of 
    $1^\text{st}, 2^\text{nd}, and 3^\text{rd}$ arrivals,......? provided that these arrival time values lie within $[0,1 \text{ s}]$***.

My Question is, if I know the expectation value of the arrival time of the $1^\text{st}$ arrival, as $E[X_1\mid 0<X_1<1\text{ s}]$.

Its obvious that the expected value of the arrival time of the $2^\text{nd}$ would be greater than the $1^\text{st}$ arrival. Therefore, is it right to compute, 
$$E[\ X_2\mid (E[X_1\mid 0<X_1<1\text{ s}]) <X_2< 1\text{ s}].$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ask for $E(X_k|X_k<1)$ where $X_k$ is the arrival time of the $k$-th arrival in the Poisson process, which is distributed gamma($k,\lambda$) (note the condition $X_k>0$ is redundant). This is, by definition, equal to
$$E(X_k \cdot 1_{X_k<1})/P(X_k<1),$$
where $1_A$ represents the indicator function of the set $A$.

The PDF of $X_k$ is $f_{X_k}(x)=\frac{\lambda^k}{(k-1)!} x^{k-1} e^{-\lambda x}$ and $P(X_k<1)=F_{X_k}(1)$ where $F$ is the CDF. Thus, the above expression can be written as,
$$\frac{\int_0^1 \frac{\lambda^k}{(k-1)!} x^{k} e^{-\lambda x} dx}{1-e^{-\lambda}(1+\lambda+\lambda^2+\dotso+\lambda^{k-1})}$$

By the way, the whole idea of conditioning on the event that the mean arrival time of the first arrival is less than the mean time for the second arrival is moot. Expected values are no longer random, so the probability $P(E(X_1)<E(X_2))$ is undefined hence so is the conditional expectation $E(X_2 | E(X_1)<E(X_2))$. Any questions?

**EDIT**
For arbitrary $t>0$, we have
$$E(X_k | X_k<t)=\frac{\int_0^t \frac{\lambda^k}{(k-1)!} x^{k} e^{-\lambda x} dx}{1-e^{-\lambda t}(1+\lambda t+(\lambda t)^2+\dotso+(\lambda t)^{k-1})}$$

and specifically for $k=1$ and $k=2$, i.e. the first and second arrival times, this is simplified to,
$$E(X_1 |X_1 <t)=\frac{1}{\lambda} +\frac{t}{1-e^{\lambda t}}$$
and

$$E(X_2 | X_2<t)=\frac{2}{\lambda} +\frac{\lambda t^2}{\lambda t+1-e^{\lambda t}},$$
although you should check these yourself by computing the expression for the values of $k$.

Comment: Dear @LoveTooNap29 Many thanks and I second that.
However, yes I still has quesiton, can you please see the ADDED DATA part in my post. I added info about my question after your proposal. The confusion is for when $t$ is a small time value. I explained in the post. PLease see it. I would be happy if you can further help me to get rid of this confusion.

Comment: @Hallian1990 Please see the edit. The formula you reproduced for your simulation is slightly incorrect. In my original answer, I gave you $E(X_k | X_k<1)$ and your attempt to generalize it to $E(X_k | X_k <t)$ is off by not including the dependence of $t$ in the denominator--your expressions read as $E(X_k \cdot 1_{X_k<t} )/P(X_k<1)$, while they should be $E(X_k \cdot 1_{X_k<t} )/P(X_k<t)$; notice the dependence of $t$ in the denominator. I also included simplified expressions for $k=1,2$. I hope this helps.

Comment: Dear @LoveTooNap29, Many thanks. Actually I did for $k=1$. But my expression is different than yours. The results for $k=1$ are perfect for all $t$ values. I showed in graph. 
\begin{align*}
E[X_{1}|X_{1}\le t]&=\int_{0}^t x_1f_{X_1|X_1 \le t}(x_1)dx_1\\&=\frac{1}{P(x_1 \le t)}\int_{0}^t x_1 f_{x_1}(x_1)dx_1\\&=\frac{1}{1-e^{-\lambda t}}\int_{0}^t x_1 \lambda e^{-\lambda x_1}dx_1\\&=\frac{-(te^{-\lambda t}+\frac{1}{\lambda}e^{-\lambda t}-\frac{1}{\lambda})}{1-e^{-\lambda t}} \\&=\frac{1}{\lambda}-\frac{te^{-\lambda t}}{1-e^{-\lambda t}}
\end{align*}

Comment: The expressions are equivalent. Simply multiply the second term by $e^{\lambda t}/e^{\lambda t}$ and then bring the minus sign to the denominator.

Comment: That's I agree. But in the second term of your expression, it should be $t$ in the numerator instead of $1$. Isn't it?

Comment: Dear @LoveTooNap29. I have to admire your help here. Yes,  for $k=1$, in the second term of your expression, it should be $t$ in the numerator instead of $1$. Moreover, the wrong curve for $k=2$ gets corrected now after using your proposal. Thank you again.

Comment: @Hallian1990 you are right. That is a typo on my part. Thanks for checking. Ill edit the answer so it is correct.